# How to make a top menu central

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my top menu central

As you can see I've tried to experiment with padding but that only works if the screen is the exact same size each time.

```css
#topnav {
    background-color: #1a1919;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 150px;
    margin: 0px 160px;
}
#topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
#topnav a:hover {
    color: rgb(26, 131, 22);
}
#topnav a.active {
    background-color: #1e7521;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="topnav">
            <a href="file:///C:/Users/Haess/OneDrive/Skrivbord/Aromanticism.html">About Aromanticism</a>
            <a>Where to find out more</a>
            <a>Forum</a>
        </div>
```

Also, I'm guessing the reason my #topnav a.active color doesn't show up is that I can't just link to file on my computer, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```css
body {
  margin: unset;
}

/* Padding-left and margin properties removed. Text-align added. */
#topnav {
  background-color: #1a1919;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Float and text-align properties removed. Display added. */
#topnav a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#topnav a:hover {
  color: rgb(26, 131, 22);
}
#topnav a.active {
  background-color: #1e7521;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="topnav">
  <a href="file:///C:/Users/Haess/OneDrive/Skrivbord/Aromanticism.html">About Aromanticism</a>
  <a>Where to find out more</a>
  <a>Forum</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

a.active needs to be a: and to center items use flex

```css
#topnav {
    background-color: #1a1919;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: bold;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}
#topnav a {
   
    color: #f2f2f2;
    margin:0 20px;
    
    
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
#topnav a:hover {
    color: rgb(26, 131, 22);
}
#topnav a:active {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="topnav">
            <a href="file:///C:/Users/Haess/OneDrive/Skrivbord/Aromanticism.html">About Aromanticism</a>
            <a>Where to find out more</a>
            <a>Forum</a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how your html is structured but you can try something like this,

```
#topnav {
    background-color: #1a1919;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute; 
    top: amount you want from the top of page;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%)
}
```